# PHP - Google Sheets API OAuth2- can't get token

Tags: php, access-token, google-sheets-api

i am trying to create a token/refreshToken so my website will be able to submit data to Google Sheets without asking the end user for permissions and i am struggling with this for few hours now..

I tried many different codes i found on the web + Google's docs and i made some progress but i can't get it to work and i can't figure what i am missing..

At this point i get no error (neither in my logs) but also i don't get any redirect or new window for authorizing the app

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once('php-google-oauth/Google_Client.php');
    include_once('lib/autoload.php');
    include_once('php-google-oauth/auth/Google_OAuth2.php');

    $CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    $SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $REDIRECT = 'http://mywebsite.com';
    $APIKEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    // $KEY = file_get_contents('php-google-oauth/client_secret.json');

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Contacts to Google Sheets");
    $client->setClientId($CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret($SECRET);
    $client->setRedirectUri($REDIRECT);
    $client->setScopes(array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'));
    $client->setAccessType('offline');   // Gets us our refresh token

    // Step 1:  The user has not authenticated so we give them a link to login
    if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    }

    // Step 2: The user accepted your access now you need to exchange it.
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($REDIRECT, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    // Step 3: We have access we can now create our service
    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    }

    echo '<script>console.log("TOKEN: '. $token .'");</script>';
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to check this [Github](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) if it can help you. It can be serve as a guide in you if you properly set your code. Also, make sure that you read this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing) about Authorizing Request in Sheets API. Another thing is you should enable the Sheets API in your Developer Console to access this API. For more information, check this [thread](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client/issues/20).

Answer (score 0):

I looked at my code and tried this-

```
// Step 1:  The user has not authenticated so we give them a link to login
if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    echo '<a href="'. $authUrl . '">Click here</a>';
}
```

and now i do get a token back from Google